# cakephp, giving a cake form custom styling

Tags: css, forms, cakephp

How to I over ride the basic styling for a form in cakePHP? I think the default limits the width of a form to 40% but I need one of my forms to be 100%.

Is something like this the way to go?

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Quote', array('novalidate' => true, 'div' => array('class' => 'div-class'), 'before' => '<div class="quotes-form">', 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's any number of ways to do this.

One way would be to do what you're doing. Another would be to not bother with that, and just edit Cake's default css directly, so all forms get styled the way you want.

UPDATE:

You could just do it like this:

```
<div class="quotes-form">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Quote', array('novalidate' => true, 'div' => array('class' => 'div-class'))); ?>
    <?php // rest of your form elements go here ?>
</div>
```

Then your css can just be like

```
.quotes-form form {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: We've sort of worked with cakes default so far but there is just one form that we really need to be different. The code I posted doesn't work however, is there something wrong with it or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Just put your <div class="quotes-form"> in plain html, outside the form itself. That should give you a handle which you can use to style that form. I've updated my answer with more info.